# Why are the cards not appearing on JPanel CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

My application consists of two `JPanel`s that will be cards on a `MainPanel`. The code is as below. For some reason, the panels don't appear. I'd be very grateful for your help :)

**MainPanel.java:**

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    private final static String PANEL1 = "PANEL1";
    private final static String PANEL2 = "PANEL2";

    private static Panel1 panel1;
    private static Panel2 panel2;

    //private static CardLayout layout;

    public MainPanel() {

        super(new CardLayout());

        panel1 = new Panel1();
        panel2 = new Panel2();

        getLayout().addLayoutComponent(PANEL1, panel1);
        getLayout().addLayoutComponent(PANEL2, panel2);


        ((CardLayout) getLayout()).show(this, PANEL1); 
    }

}
```

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main {

    private static JFrame window;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        window = new JFrame();

        window.setContentPane(new MainPanel());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(600,400);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
getLayout().addLayoutComponent(PANEL1, panel1);
getLayout().addLayoutComponent(PANEL2, panel2);
```

should be

```
add(panel1, PANEL1);
add(panel2, PANEL2);
```

For more information, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: @W.K.S, I'm referring to `JPanel#add`.